# VirtualHost : php_value enable_post_data_reading Off : for ONE webpage

Tags: php, post, url-rewriting, virtualhost, multipartform-data

I'm trying to manually parse one page on my website with multipart form data sent from a Java application. All the pages are served inside the index file in the public_html directory, and my classes for my other pages rely heavily on `$_POST` data being populated.

I can parse the multipart data if I set:

```
php_value enable_post_data_reading Off
```

But then my other pages error out for un-populated `$_POST` data.

How can I turn off `$_POST` reading for this one page in my content directory and leave it on for all my other pages?

My VirtualHost is as follows (only works with the one page):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName elementbox.lampllc.com

    DocumentRoot /var/element.lampllc.com/public_html

    CustomLog     /var/element.lampllc.com/access.log combined
    ErrorLog      /var/element.lampllc.com/error.log
    LogLevel info
    /*THIS IS THE FIX*/
    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'mod=APIlogin'">
        php_value enable_post_data_reading Off
    </If>

    <Directory "/var/element.lampllc.com/public_html/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/index/(.+)$       /index.php?mod=$1       [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried specifying the file in question with

```
<Files "myfile">
```

I've tried making an alias for a directory and setting a Directory directive for it outside of my "mod" directory (where my content is) but I get rewrite errors.

UPDATED WITH ANSWER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an `If` condition:

```
<If "%{SCRIPT_URI} == '/myfile.php'">
    php_value enable_post_data_reading Off
</If>
```

Comment: I tried alot of IF directives, this worked for me. I appreciate it as I hadn't considered the IF directive yet.

    `<If "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'mod=APIlogin'">
        php_value enable_post_data_reading Off
    </If>`